# Pandas Plot, arrange bar value from high to low, and colour Individual bar separately

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a series as below:

```
Country
India                                                   691904
China                                                   659962
United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland    551500
Philippines                                             511391
Pakistan                                                241600
United States of America                                241122
Iran (Islamic Republic of)                              175923
Sri Lanka                                               148358
Republic of Korea                                       142581
```

After i plotted a horizontal bar graph, the graph x-axis was arranged from low to high

**Q:**
**1) How can I arrange the y-axis from High to Low?**

**2) Is there any easier way to colour all bar grey except for highest value (in this case India)  without typing all the country name?**

Thanks!

```
ax = top15.plot(kind='barh',
             figsize=(20,10),
               color = {'red':'India'})

ax.set_title('Immigration from 1980 - 2013')
ax.set_xlabel('Total Number')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Firstly use `sort_values()`:

```
top15=top15.sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Finally:

```
color=['0.8','0.8','0.8','0.8','0.8','0.8','0.8','0.8','r']
#created a list of colors

ax = top15.plot(kind='barh',
             figsize=(20,10),
               color = color)

ax.set_title('Immigration from 1980 - 2013')
ax.set_xlabel('Total Number')
```

Output:

[image]